# JQuery-UI accordion image file ui-icons_595959_256x240.png NOT found

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using JqueryUI in my project and I am having trouble displaying down arrow on click of a accordion section.

I get the error that ui-icons_595959_256x240.png file is missing. I checked the images folder of JQueryUI plugin that I downloaded, but could not find image with this name.

I am not sure if this is case of missing file or wrong linking. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the file from link below:

https://github.com/colmilloblanco/scm/blob/master/scm/static/css/custom-theme/images/ui-icons_595959_256x240.png